Calculate Total hours some has logged in and remove the overlapping hours in that total
I have an Excel spreadsheet that of sign in time on different days for any given day I want to be able to calculate the amount of time someone is logged in. However, the entries for a given day often overlap and I want to be able to remove this overlap in time from the totaling of the hours.  I believe the code will work but there is no way to store time as a time variable either date or a double.
This is what the data for one day look like



First
MiddleI
LastName
Date
LoginDTime
LogoutDTime




Sandy

Cheeks
10/23/2023
10/23/23 9:00
10/23/23 13:29


Sandy

Cheeks
10/23/2023
10/23/23 9:02
10/23/23 12:26


Sandy

Cheeks
10/23/2023
10/23/23 12:33
10/23/23 13:27


Sandy

Cheeks
10/23/2023
10/23/23 14:29
10/23/23 16:27


Sandy

Cheeks
10/23/2023
10/23/23 16:30
10/23/23 17:00



Where the columns are set up like this

Column A is Firstname
Column B is Middle Intial
Column C is LastName
Column D is Date
Column E is LoginDTime (This is a data type data with hour and minute)
Column F is LogoutDTime (This is a data type data with hour and minute)
Column H is Where

Sub CalculateTotalLoggedInTime()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim totalLoggedInTime As Double
    Dim previousLogoutTime As Double
    Dim loginTime As Double
    Dim logoutTime As Double
    
    ' Assuming your data is in Sheet1
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Find the last row with data in column D
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Initialize variables
    totalLoggedInTime = 0
    previousLogoutTime = 0
    
    ' Loop through each row of data
    For i = 2 To lastRow ' Assuming row 1 contains headers
        ' Convert login and logout times to numeric values (doubles)
        loginTime = TimeValue(ws.Cells(i, 5).Value)
        logoutTime = TimeValue(ws.Cells(i, 6).Value)
        
        ' Check for overlap and adjust the previous logout time if necessary
        If loginTime <= previousLogoutTime Then
            previousLogoutTime = Application.Max(previousLogoutTime, logoutTime)
        Else
            ' Add the logged-in time
            totalLoggedInTime = totalLoggedInTime + (logoutTime - loginTime) * 24 ' Convert hours to a numeric value
            previousLogoutTime = logoutTime
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Display the total logged-in time
    MsgBox "Total logged-in time: " & totalLoggedInTime & " hours"
End Sub


This will process each row in turn, adjusting for any later rows where the period overlaps, and sum up the times:
Sub CalculateTotalLoggedInTime()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, r As Long, n As Long, arr, arrSkip
    Dim totalLoggedInTime As Double, numRows As Long
    
    Dim rS As Double, cS As Double, rE As Double, cE As Double
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'for example
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    
    arr = ws.Range("E2:F" & lastRow).Value 'read times into an array
    numRows = UBound(arr, 1)               'how many rows of data
    ReDim arrSkip(1 To numRows) 'for flagging rows to be skipped
    
    ' Loop through each row of data and compare with following rows
    For r = 1 To numRows
        If arrSkip(r) <> True Then 'use this line?
            rS = arr(r, 1) 'reference period Start/End date-time values
            rE = arr(r, 2)
            'scan all rows below for possible overlap
            For n = r + 1 To numRows
                If arrSkip(r) <> True Then 'check this row?
                    cS = arr(n, 1)          'comparison Start/End date-time values
                    cE = arr(n, 2)

                    'any overlap with the reference period values?
                    If (cS >= rS And cS <= rE) Or (cE >= rS And cE <= rE) Then
                        If cS < rS Then rS = cS 'adjust reference start if needed
                        If cE > rE Then rE = cE 'adjust reference end if needed
                        arrSkip(n) = True         'skip this row later
                    End If
                End If
            Next n
            
            totalLoggedInTime = totalLoggedInTime + (rE - rS) 'add the time for this row
            
        End If 'anything to look at?
    Next r
    
    Debug.Print "Total time", Round(totalLoggedInTime * 24, 2) & " hrs"
    
End Sub

...or another way to do it (should scale OK as long as your total time spans aren't very long):
Sub SlightlyDifferentApproach()
    
    Const MINSPERDAY As Long = 1440 '24*60 minutes per day
    Dim s As String, minS, maxE, rng As Range
    Dim i As Long, vS, vE, minsStart As Long, minsLen As Long, totMin
    
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:F6") 'for example
    minS = Application.Min(rng.Columns(1)) 'earliest login
    maxE = Application.Max(rng.Columns(2)) 'latest logout
    
    'create a string of spaces of length (max end - min start) in minutes
    s = String(MINSPERDAY * (maxE - minS), " ")
    
    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        vS = rng(i, 1).Value 'datetime start
        vE = rng(i, 2).Value 'datetime end
        minsStart = (vS - minS) * MINSPERDAY 'relative to earliest login
        minsLen = (vE - vS) * MINSPERDAY     'period length in minutes
        'Debug.Print "Start min", minsStart, "# of mins", minsLen
        Mid(s, minsStart + 1, minsLen) = String(minsLen, "X") 'set the "bits" in `s` for this period
    Next i
    
    totMin = Len(s) - Len(Replace(s, "X", "")) 'count all X's in the string
    Debug.Print totMin / 60, "hours"

End Sub


I tend to use the Gap and Island method to do these as demonstrated with helper columns here originally and followed up with a VBA solution and a Lambda.
As long as the login and logout times are sorted in ascending order of login time, you can identify a gap as the time between the latest logout time so far and the next login time, then just subtract the total gap time from the total elapsed time to find the time active:
Sub GapAndIsland()

    Dim varData As Variant
    Dim minStart As Variant
    Dim maxEnd As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim gap As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim numRows As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    


    ' Set the array
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    
    varData = ws.Range("E2:F" & lastRow).Value
    numRows = UBound(varData, 1)

    varData = Range("e2:f" & lastRow).Value
       
    ' Sort if necessary
    
    'varData = Application.Sort(varData, 1, 1, false)

    ' Initialise
      
    minStart = varData(1, 1)
    maxEnd = varData(1, 1)
    gap = 0
    
    ' Loop over rows


    For i = 1 To numRows
    
    ' If there is a gap, increment total gap length
    
        If (varData(i, 1)) > maxEnd Then
            gap = gap + varData(i, 1) - maxEnd
        End If
        
    ' Update latest end time
        
        If varData(i, 2) > maxEnd Then
            maxEnd = varData(i, 2)
            
        End If
        
    Next i
    
    Debug.Print ("Gap=" & Round(gap * 24, 2) & " hours")

    Debug.Print ("Total=" & Round((maxEnd - minStart) * 24, 2) & " hours")

    Debug.Print ("Active=" & Round((maxEnd - minStart - gap) * 24, 2) & " hours")

End Sub



I investigated the use of worksheetfunction.sort for the case where data was not presented in ascending order of login time. Unfortunately there appear to be some issues with receiving output from this and I was unable to coerce the result from string to a decimal number so used a workaround of splitting each datetime into date and time and converting them separately:
Sub GapAndIslandSort()

    Dim varData As Variant
    Dim minStart As Double
    Dim maxEnd As Double
    Dim i As Long
    Dim gap As Double
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim numRows As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim s As String
    Dim doubleData() As Double


    ' Set the array
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    
    varData = ws.Range("E2:F" & lastRow).Value
    numRows = UBound(varData, 1)
       
    ' Sort if necessary
    
    ReDim doubleData(numRows, 2)
    
    varData = WorksheetFunction.Sort(varData, 1, 1, False)
    
    For i = 1 To numRows
        For j = 1 To 2
            s = varData(i, j)
            ' There are two spaces between date and time
            doubleData(i, j) = DateValue(Split(s)(0)) + TimeValue(Split(s)(2))
        Next j
    Next i

    ' Initialise

    minStart = doubleData(1, 1)
    maxEnd = doubleData(1, 1)
    gap = 0
    
    ' Loop over rows


    For i = 1 To numRows
    
    ' If there is a gap, increment total gap length
    
        If (doubleData(i, 1)) > maxEnd Then
            gap = gap + doubleData(i, 1) - maxEnd
        End If
        
    ' Update latest end time
        
        If doubleData(i, 2) > maxEnd Then
            maxEnd = doubleData(i, 2)
            
        End If
        
    Next i
    
    Debug.Print ("Gap=" & Round(gap * 24, 2) & " hours")

    Debug.Print ("Total=" & Round((maxEnd - minStart) * 24, 2) & " hours")

    Debug.Print ("Active=" & Round((maxEnd - minStart - gap) * 24, 2) & " hours")

End Sub

Changing the first login time to 13:00 to test the sorting, my results were:


From me, a proposal to combine VBA with Excel formulas.
The concept of the solution is to convert time data into minutes relative to the earliest value. These minutes are then interpreted as the boundaries of the row ranges. The union of these ranges should be evaluated. There is no Excel function for this, so I used the Uni function defined in VBA. Then the rows of this union that you received should be counted. Again, the Excel ROWS function is useless because it counts rows only in contiguous ranges, so I used the VBA CountRows function. In the end, the resulting sum of rows (=minutes) is divided by 60 to get the hours.
Formulas used:
C2 :    =ROUND((A2-$A$2)*24*60+1, 0)&":"&ROUND((B2-$A$2)*24*60, 0)
C8 :    =CountRows(REDUCE(0, C2:C6, LAMBDA(a,b, uni(a, INDIRECT(b)))))/60

UDF functions:
Function Uni(rng1, rng2) As Range
   If TypeName(rng1) <> "Range" Then
       Set Uni = rng2
   ElseIf TypeName(rng2) <> "Range" Then
       Set Uni = rng1
   Else
       Set Uni = Union(rng1, rng2)
   End If
End Function

Function CountRows(rng As Range) As Long
   Dim area As Range
   For Each area In rng.Areas
       CountRows = CountRows + area.Rows.Count
   Next area
End Function


